# Detect SignalR client connection loss

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr

I'm working on developing an ASP.Net core 6 application with SignalR, where an android application connects to this service.

I'm performing connection and disconnection tests and when performing the connection loss test in the app, where, I'm disabling the android connection on server side the signalr disconnect runs after 10 minutes.

How can I reduce this time?
In SignalR settings I'm using all the default timeouts

Comment: what is `signalr disconnect runs after 10 minutes`, did you mean that after you stopping the server, then the android signalr client triggered `connection.onclose` ?

Answer (score 0):

I think your issue or requirement is get some guidance about how to set the default disconnection time on the sever side, so this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-server-options-1) may help you.

`KeepAliveInterval` is 15s by default and it indicates how long after the ping message should be sent from server to the client to keep the connection open.